# window.print(); function opening browse-print window along with image on UI

Tags: lightning-web-components

Using DIV to show/hide an image on BOOL value using window.print() to print.(screen 3).

On page load 'ShowImage=false', DIV is hidden. On printImgBtn click browser 'ShowImage=True' and print option showing with an image. Problem is same image is also showing on UI(because div is enabled) (screen 2). How to hide same image on UI but still showing on browser print option.

Using  `<div class="slds-col slds-no-print" >` in other div's to hide Div from print option.

javascript code:

```
    printDiv(){
        this.showImage = true;
        window.print();
        
    }
```

Html code:

```
   <div class="slds-col slds-no-print">  
     <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" id="printDivBtn" onclick={printDiv} value="print a div!"> Print Button </button>
    </div>
```

```
<template>
   <div if:true={showImage} id="showImg" > <img src={LabelImage}  style="transform:rotate(180deg);">   </div>

</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this:

```
@media screen {
  #showImg {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media print {
  #showImg {
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

This is a no-script solution; you don't need to hide the elements using a Boolean property or any other sort of logic.