# LWC save or print as pdf

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, printpdf

I have built out an LWC to that I'm displaying externally in a community (public). I trying to put a print/save button on the LWC to print/save the LWC as a PDF. I've looked into jspdf and some others, but they seem to only be able to convert the contents of a VF page to PDF or convert content that is built in js to PDF. I would prefer not to rebuild my content in VF or js.

Is there a way to just put a print/save button on the LWC page that will print/save my LWC as a PDF?

Comment: Easiest option I have found is just to call the standard print function via JS and tell folks to use the Print to PDF option. I believe some of the Industry solution in SF have a PDF Creator, but definitely lacking in standard platform.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - cool - can you point me to an example of this being done in an LWC?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362699/window-print-function-opening-browse-print-window-along-with-image-on-ui

Comment: Seems like the link shared is intended for creating PDFs from a LWC, not a PDF of the LWC. ----- @mackmama, did you find a solution? If so, would you mind posting it here for others' benefit? I find myself in the same situation as you, but I can't figure out a way to do this. I'll happily upvote your answer if/when you post it. Thanks!